# Convert uploaded file to GIF and then POST to web service

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, python-requests

I need to take an uploaded JPG from `request.FILES`, convert it to a GIF thumbnail and then POST it to a 3rd party web service.

```
import StringIO
import Image
import requests

img_file = request.FILES['files[]'] if request.FILES else None

#create the thumbnail
import StringIO
thumb_buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
im = Image.open(img_file)
im.thumbnail(settings.THUMBNAIL_SIZE)
im.save(thumb_buffer, "GIF")
thumb_buffer.seek(0)
thumb_contents = thumb_buffer.getvalue()
thumb_buffer.close()

#send file via POST request
thumb_upload_dict = {
    'upload_file': (filename + '.gif', thumb_contents)}
print thumb_upload_dict
thumb_payload = {
    'func': 'upload_file',
    'base_id': new_asset.base_id,
    'type': 'GIF',
    'username': 'remote_admin',
    'password': 'we1398fj'
}
r = requests.post(url, params=thumb_payload, files=thumb_upload_dict)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.  When I try to view the image I get `The image “http://theurl.com/gif_filename.gif” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.`

I should note that if I just POST `img_file` without converting it, it works fine.  I'm guessing the problem has to do with thumb_contents but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: If you save the `thumb_contents` to a file rather than posting it, do you get a valid GIF file?